# In Macroable.php line 104: Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::id does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

When I do a migration by using the command php artisan migrate I have this error: In Macroable.php line 104:    Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::id does not exist.
I don't understand where this error arises from.
Do you have an idea please?

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFilesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('files');
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Manually delete "config.php", "packages.php", "services.php" from "bootstrap/cache" folder. 2. Run "php artisan config:cache", 3. Try again

Comment: Thanks boolfalse. I solve it by running the command "php artisan cache:clear"

Comment: Now How can I close this discussion?